# Calendar Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar

Goodmorning everyone,
I'm using calendar angularjs with the library fullcalendar.js. The place is allday (located in the seventh day) should I add the buttons. So I'm wondering how do you angular? In the library fullcalendar.js renderhtml should I use, but I do not know how to use it. I ask you a hand.

Here is my code:

fullcalendar.js the part I should change in angularjs

```
renderHtml: function() {
        return '' +
            '<table>' +
                '<thead class="fc-head">' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td class="' + this.widgetHeaderClass + '">' +
                            this.timeGrid.headHtml() + // render the day-of-week headers
                        '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</thead>' +
                '<tbody class="fc-body">' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td class="' + this.widgetContentClass + '">' +
                            (this.dayGrid ?
                                '<div class="fc-day-grid"/>' +
                                '<hr class="fc-divider ' + this.widgetHeaderClass + '"/>' :
                                ''
                                ) +
                            '<div class="fc-time-grid-container">' +
                                '<div class="fc-time-grid"/>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</tbody>' +
            '</table>';
    },
```

Comment: please provide plunker .it's diffucult

Answer (score 0):

```
fullcalendar.js the aprte I should change in angularjs
renderHtml: function() {
        return '' +
            '<table>' +
                '<thead class="fc-head">' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td class="' + this.widgetHeaderClass + '">' +
                            this.timeGrid.headHtml() + // render the day-of-week headers
                        '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</thead>' +
                '<tbody class="fc-body">' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td class="' + this.widgetContentClass + '">' +
                            (this.dayGrid ?
                                '<div class="fc-day-grid"/>' +
                                '<hr class="fc-divider ' + this.widgetHeaderClass + '"/>' :
                                ''
                                ) +
                            '<div class="fc-time-grid-container">' +
                                '<div class="fc-time-grid"/>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</tbody>' +
            '</table>';
    },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Additional explanation would improve your answer.